# Update record ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a few problems and this is my source code:
**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Order> list = new List<Order>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Order());
    }
    list = DatabaseService.DBGetList<Order>("Order");
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (list[i].numberOfCompleted == 0)
        {
            orders.Add(new Order() { id = list[i].id, numberOfCompleted = list[i].numberOfCompleted, customerName = list[i].customerName, foods = list[i].foods });
        }
    }
    return View(orders);
}
```

**Order.cs**

```
public List<Food> foods { get; set; }
public string customerName { get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public long totalCost = 0;
public int numberOfCompleted { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <!--Display attributes-->
    <!--Display Complete button-->
                <div class="media-container-column col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                    <div class="mbr-section-btn align-right py-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary display-4 remove"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#exampleModal"
                                type="submit"
                                >Complete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

I want when clicking the Complete button, the `numberOfComplete` attribute will be assigned with `food.Count()`. What do I have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First you create a post form in `view` page of `index` action. Change this to your `index.cshtml` file.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <!--Display attributes-->
    <!--Display Complete button-->
    <div class="media-container-column col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
    @Html.BeginForm("Index","Controller",FormMethod.post)
    {
        <input type="text" name="id" display="none" value="@item.id"/>
        <div class="mbr-section-btn align-right py-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary display-4 remove" data-toggle="modal" data- 
            target="#exampleModal" type="submit">Complete</button>
        </div>
    }
    </div>        
}
```

Then create post action method of `index`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Order obj)
{
    Order order=Order().Find(x=>x.id=obj.id);
    order.numberOfComplete = order.food.count();
    return view();
}
```